How to get the value from a proxy object in Vue js
I am trying to access the value of the "color" from a proxy object.
This is my code
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({status:Object});
    
function getColor(items){
    const currentStatus = props.status;

    const output = currentStatus.filter((item)=>{
            if(items.status === item.status){
                return item
            }
    })

    return output.color;
    //return output.["color"];
    //return (output, "color");

}

</script>

<template>
    <div class="p-5">
         <v-data-table
             :search="search"
             :headers="headers"
             :items="transactions">
             <template v-slot:[`item.status`]="{item}">
                 <v-chip :color="getColor(item)" variant="elevated" label>{{ item.status }}</v-chip>
             </template>
         </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template> 

this is the snap image of the data am getting after the filter

I hope someone will point out what missing here.
thanks

.filter returns an ARRAY ... arrays don't traditionally have a .color

Yeah I may haven't realize that but may goal is to get the value of color from this object. I also edited the post for more clarity. Thanks

output is an array ... it won't have a color property ... do you know how array's work? an array can include a single item, but it's still an array, and is accessed like any other array. This issue has nothing to do with proxy object. perhaps you wanted to use .find instead of .filter

@Edson It's return props.status.find(i => items.status === i.status))?.color

I got it by using for loop.
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(output)){
        return value.color;
    }


This is how plain objects are iterated, not arrays. It's possible to do this because arrays are objects but it's awkward and makes code complicated. output shouldn't be an array in the first place if it's only 1 item
